# Is it possible to display a binary Word document into task pane for word web add-in?

Tags: office-js

Imagine we have Word documents stored on a SP document library.
Currently we need to use REST API to get the binary of a Word document(we are able to do this part) 
Next, we want to be able to display the content of this document onto the Word add-in task pane so that my user could select portions of this document (from the task pane)  onto the main document area in Word. This is where we need some help and pointers. Please guide.

Comment: Can you have users open the SP site in the task pane and then open the Word document in the library?

Comment: Thanks - could you please guide on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can redirect the task pane to a SharePoint library URL using the window.location property, just like redirecting in a web application.